# Django 1.7 request.FILES 'None' not validated (is_valid())

Tags: python, django, file, validation, django-1.7

So I extended the User model to add some fields and am having troubles with the image (avatar) POST part. First there is a profile page that displays the user information, along with a link to edit the latter.
Once on the 'editprofile' page, the form is loaded and prepopulated with existing data. When an avatar file is uploaded, everything works fine. But when no avatar is uploaded (whether the userprofile already has one or not), the is_valid() method fails like so :

```
Request Method:     POST
Django Version:     1.7.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:     invalid file: None
Exception location:  /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/files/images.py in get_image_dimensions, line 46
```

My question is : how do I pass validation with an empty field (value None) in request.FILES ?

Here's my code.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from famsite import settings
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField('Date of birth', null=True)
    phone1 = models.CharField('Primary phone', null=True, blank=True, max_length=15)
    phone2 = models.CharField('Secondary phone', null=True, blank=True, max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField('Address', null=True, blank=True, max_length=256)
    avatar = ImageField('Avatar', upload_to='usrprofile/', blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as u_
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
import datetime

from usrprofile.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']
        fields = ['birth_date', 'phone1', 'phone2', 'email', 'address', 'avatar']

    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=[y for y in range(1950, datetime.date.today().year)]))
    email = forms.EmailField()


    def clean_avatar(self):
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']

        try:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)

            #validate dimensions
            max_width = max_height = 100
            if w > max_width or h > max_height:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u_('Please use an image that is '
                     '%s x %s pixels or smaller.') % (max_width, max_height))

            #validate content type
            main, sub = avatar.content_type.split('/')
            if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'png']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u_('Please use a JPEG, '
                    'GIF or PNG image.'))

            #validate file size
            if len(avatar) > (20 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u_('Avatar file size may not exceed 20k.'))

        except AttributeError:
            """
            Handles case when we are updating the user profile
            and do not supply a new avatar
            """
            pass

        return avatar
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django import forms
from django.template import RequestContext
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
from usrprofile.models import UserProfile
from usrprofile.forms import *



class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'usrprofile/profile.html'


def edit(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
#deletes old file in case of new file upload
        form_aux = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_aux.is_valid() and 'avatar' in request.FILES:
            user.userprofile.avatar.delete()
#check if form has changed
#if form has changed, check if form is valid
#if form is valid, save data, associate with userprofile, save data to server        
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.has_changed():
            if form.is_valid():
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
                return render_to_response('usrprofile/profile.html', RequestContext(request))
    else:
#if GET method, populate form with existing data
        profile = user.userprofile
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile, initial={'email': user.email})

    return render_to_response('usrprofile/editprofile.html', RequestContext(request, {'form' : form}))
```

**editprofile.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% trans "Profile edition" %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}

        <form id="form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>

    {% endblock %}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `required` argument of `ImageField` (neither Django's nor sorl.thumbnail's). In your model definition, instead of

```
avatar = ImageField('Avatar', upload_to='usrprofile/', required=False)
```

try

```
avatar = ImageField('Avatar', upload_to='usrprofile/', blank=True)
```

Comment: Since I have "Exception location:  /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/files/images.py in get_image_dimensions, line 46"; Could it be because i'm missing some libraries (but Pillow is properly installed) ?

Comment: Ok I finally found the problem, which lies at this line in my forms.py : "try: w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)". I rectified with by changing except AttributeError to TypeError. Solved, thnx for the brain stimulation :), wasted 8 hours on this :(